# Keyboard back button event KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK not working after updating to Android 13

Tags: android, keyboard-events, android-13, targetsdkversion

I have upgraded targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion to 33.
After that the keyboard back event is not getting triggered.

As per the Android document, it is suggested to migrate to Predictive back gesture.
I have tried with the suggested solution to use OnBackInvokedDispatcher and OnBackPressedCallback but none of them helping to get the keyboard back event.

```
// Add onBackPressed as default back behavior.
        mDefaultBackCallback = this::onBackPressed;
        getOnBackInvokedDispatcher().registerOnBackInvokedCallback(
                OnBackInvokedDispatcher.PRIORITY_DEFAULT, mDefaultBackCallback);
        mDefaultBackCallback = null;
```

Before updating to Android 13, I was able to get the callback on

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {resetView();}
    return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event);
}
```

Any help on this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you tried this one

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
       Log.d("Test","Back Pressed");
       return viewModel.backClicked();
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Yes. I have tried this as well but still its not getting back press event.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem that my implemantation for `AppCompatEditText` was not longer working.

I was using:

```
class CustomAppCompatEditText : AppCompatEditText {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
    context,
    attrs,
    defStyleAttr
    )

    override fun onKeyPreIme(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            clearFocus()
        }
        return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event)
    }

    override fun onEditorAction(actionCode: Int) {
        if (actionCode == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            clearFocus()
        }
        super.onEditorAction(actionCode)
    }

}
```

I created a new class called `KeyboardHelper`.
It looks like this:

```
object KeyboardHelper {

    fun View?.clearFocusOnKeyboardHidden() {
        var wasOpened = false
        val listener = ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            val isOpen = isKeyboardVisible(this@clearFocusOnKeyboardHidden?.context?.getActivity())
            if (isOpen == wasOpened) {
                // The keyboard state has not changed yet!
                return@OnGlobalLayoutListener
            }
            wasOpened = isOpen
            if (this@clearFocusOnKeyboardHidden?.isFocused == true && !isOpen) {
                this@clearFocusOnKeyboardHidden.clearFocus()
            }
        }
        this?.viewTreeObserver?.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener)
    }

    private fun isKeyboardVisible(activity: Activity?): Boolean {
        activity ?: return false

        val outRect = Rect()

        val activityRoot = activity.getActivityRoot()

        activityRoot.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(outRect)

        val location = IntArray(2)
        activity.getContentRoot().getLocationOnScreen(location)

        val screenHeight = activityRoot.rootView.height
        val heightDiff = screenHeight - outRect.height() - location[1]

        return heightDiff > screenHeight * 0.15
    }

    private fun Context.getActivity(): Activity? {
        return when (this) {
            is Activity -> this
            is ContextWrapper -> this.baseContext.getActivity()
            else -> null
        }
    }

    private fun Activity.getActivityRoot(): View {
        return this.getContentRoot().rootView
    }

    private fun Activity.getContentRoot(): ViewGroup {
        return this.findViewById(android.R.id.content)
    }

}
```

Now I had done a few changes to my `CustomAppCompatEditText` class:

```
class CustomAppCompatEditText : AppCompatEditText {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyleAttr
    )

    init {
        clearFocusOnKeyboardHidden()
    }

    override fun onEditorAction(actionCode: Int) {
        if (actionCode == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            clearFocus()
        }
        super.onEditorAction(actionCode)
    }

}
```

After all it's now working as before again.
The source code of keyboard code was original from here:
https://github.com/yshrsmz/KeyboardVisibilityEvent